# How to make the jQuery Knob background color transparent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, transparency, jquery-knob

At this address you can find a beautiful plugin:

https://github.com/aterrien/jQuery-Knob

You can configure it, indicating the background and the foreground color.
I want to set a transparency on the background color. I've read something about "displayPrevious" parameter with should make this but it seems to not work correctly.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply set 'bgColor': 'rgba(0,0,0,0)' instead of a hex color, to make it transparent. Good luck